# Is there an analogue to Html.BeginForm in the Facebook SDK?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I understand how to use Html.CanvasActionLink to generate a link that resolves correctly to my Facebook iFrame app.  However, I would like to generate a POST to my iFrame app controller using Html.BeginForm and having the URL resolve correctly.  I did not see a Html.CanvasBeginForm helper, what is the suggested solution to this problem?  Write our own extension?  Using Html.BeginForm with something like Url.CanvasLink?  ... etc.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no helper for that. What we do is just add the signed_request value to the querystring of the post url. I will create a TODO item to add this though.